# Using multiple count with multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL query where I want to count the number of existence of Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 in Quarter. I have tried looking the previous questions but they weren't much clear. Here's my code:

```
SELECT  
COUNT(Quarter CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q1') 
COUNT(Quarter CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q2') 
COUNT(Quarter CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q3') 
COUNT(Quarter CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q4') 
FROM office.office;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation here.  Here is a terse way of doing this on MySQL by summing boolean expressions:

```sql
SELECT  
    SUM(Quarter = 'Q1') q1_total,
    SUM(Quarter = 'Q2') q2_total,
    SUM(Quarter = 'Q3') q3_total,
    SUM(Quarter = 'Q4') q4_total
FROM office.office;
```

If you wanted to use `COUNT`, here is the correct syntax for that:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Quarter = 'Q1' THEN 1 END) q1_total  -- and so on
```